# Good reference on stopping times and continuous time change

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

I've been trying to look at stopping times and continuous time change in martingales but have trouble understanding without some concrete examples. Anyone knows of any good references that might be helpful?

Thanks!

Comment: Williams is a good, unique, reference: http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Martingales-Cambridge-Mathematical-Textbooks/dp/0521406056

Comment: thank you! Will check it out!